# Adding a header to columns based on the values of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following different dataframes:

df1:

```
Scribe       Reduced    A    5    2.5    3    10
Reader       Reduced    A    9.2  4      12   10
Optimise     Reduced    A    5    5.8    3    12
```

df2:

```
Convert      Reduced    A    14    25  
Configure    Reduced    A    14.7  6.8      
Race         Reduced    A    2     6.3
```

df3:

```
Abstract     Reduced    A    8    7.5    9    8     4.5    11
Follower     Reduced    A    5.5  6      14   19    6      13.5
```

I would like to add a header for each of the dataframes where the column names are:

```
Class      Technique     Algorithm    1   2   3 ....
```

My issue is not with the first three columns but with the rest of the columns (integer values). As you see in the example, the number of columns for these integer values differs which makes it difficult to me how to name these columns (i.e., starting form 1 until the last value, for example, 4 in `df1`).

Can someone help me please in solving this issue?

Comment: Well in general is better not to use numeric values column headers. Try that: `make.names(names(df1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function for you. The first argument, `dat`, is your data frame. The second argument, `chr`, is the vector names for your first few columns.

```
header_fun <- function(dat, chr = c("Class", "Technique", "Algorithm")){
  dat2 <- setNames(dat, c(chr, 1:(ncol(dat) - length(chr))))
  return(dat2)
}
```

The function will return a new data frame with the updated header.

```
header_fun(df1)
#      Class Technique Algorithm  C1  C2 C3 C4
# 1   Scribe   Reduced         A 5.0 2.5  3 10
# 2   Reader   Reduced         A 9.2 4.0 12 10
# 3 Optimise   Reduced         A 5.0 5.8  3 12

header_fun(df2)
#       Class Technique Algorithm    1    2
# 1   Convert   Reduced         A 14.0 25.0
# 2 Configure   Reduced         A 14.7  6.8
# 3      Race   Reduced         A  2.0  6.3

header_fun(df3)
#      Class Technique Algorithm   1   2  3  4   5    6
# 1 Abstract   Reduced         A 8.0 7.5  9  8 4.5 11.0
# 2 Follower   Reduced         A 5.5 6.0 14 19 6.0 13.5
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Scribe       Reduced    A    5    2.5    3    10
Reader       Reduced    A    9.2  4      12   10
                  Optimise     Reduced    A    5    5.8    3    12",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "Convert      Reduced    A    14    25  
Configure    Reduced    A    14.7  6.8      
Race         Reduced    A    2     6.3",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df3 <- read.table(text = "Abstract     Reduced    A    8    7.5    9    8     4.5    11
Follower     Reduced    A    5.5  6      14   19    6      13.5",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```